# Two Windows 2012 r2 won't ping each other

Tags: networking, ping

I am creating a network for school in Virtual Box, and I have a Windows 7 machine, and two Windows Server machines. I can ping the Windows 7 to both servers; they all communicate with the the client, but the two servers won't talk to each other. I have network discovery on, I enabled all the services for it to stay on, I dropped the firewall, I don't know what the issue could be. I am trying to make a domain using one of the servers and having the client and other server connect to the domain.

```
IPs:192.168.0.1 = gateway
192.168.0.101: server 1
192.168.0.102 server 2
192.168.0.103 window 7

Server 2 info 
subnet 255.255.255.0
```

Some ipconfig info

[image]

[image]

Comment: they are just using a host only adapter

Comment: why would that be an issue? just curious?

Comment: they are all in the VM, so its a virtual environment. non of the machines are actually outside of the vm network \

Comment: with host-only you shouldn't be able to ping from outside which you were able to to, i suspect you haven't configured your host-only correctly, you can read manuals on virtual box to configure it correctly or easy way switch to bridged mode

Answer (score 1):

Bridged mode is required for the Virtual Machines to communicate with each other as well as outside world

[Virtual Box Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged)

> 6.7. Host-only networking Host-only networking is another networking mode that was added with version 2.2 of VirtualBox. It can be thought
>   of as a hybrid between the bridged and internal networking modes: as
>   with bridged networking, the virtual machines can talk to each other
>   and the host as if they were connected through a physical Ethernet
>   switch. Similarly, as with internal networking however, a physical
>   networking interface need not be present, and the virtual machines
>   cannot talk to the world outside the host since they are not connected
>   to a physical networking interface.
>
> Instead, when host-only networking is used, VirtualBox creates a new
>   software interface on the host which then appears next to your
>   existing network interfaces. In other words, whereas with bridged
>   networking an existing physical interface is used to attach virtual
>   machines to, with host-only networking a new "loopback" interface is
>   created on the host. And whereas with internal networking, the traffic
>   between the virtual machines cannot be seen, the traffic on the
>   "loopback" interface on the host can be intercepted.
>
> Host-only networking is particularly useful for preconfigured virtual
>   appliances, where multiple virtual machines are shipped together and
>   designed to cooperate. For example, one virtual machine may contain a
>   web server and a second one a database, and since they are intended to
>   talk to each other, the appliance can instruct VirtualBox to set up a
>   host-only network for the two. A second (bridged) network would then
>   connect the web server to the outside world to serve data to, but the
>   outside world cannot connect to the database.
>
> To change a virtual machine's virtual network interface to "host only"
>   mode:
>
> either go to the "Network" page in the virtual machine's settings
>   notebook in the graphical user interface and select "Host-only
>   networking", or
>
> on the command line, type VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nic
>   hostonly; see Section 8.8, “VBoxManage modifyvm” for details.
>
> Before you can attach a VM to a host-only network you have to create
>   at least one host-only interface, either from the GUI: "File" ->
>   "Preferences" -> "Network" -> "Host-only network" -> "(+)Add host-only
>   network", or via command line with
>
> VBoxManage hostonlyif create see Section 8.33, “VBoxManage hostonlyif”
>   for details.
>
> For host-only networking, like with internal networking, you may find
>   the DHCP server useful that is built into VirtualBox. This can be
>   enabled to then manage the IP addresses in the host-only network since
>   otherwise you would need to configure all IP addresses statically.
>
> In the VirtualBox graphical user interface, you can configure all
>   these items in the global settings via "File" -> "Preferences" ->
>   "Network", which lists all host-only networks which are presently in
>   use. Click on the network name and then on the "Edit" button to the
>   right, and you can modify the adapter and DHCP settings.
>
> Alternatively, you can use VBoxManage dhcpserver on the command line;
>   please see Section 8.34, “VBoxManage dhcpserver” for details.
>
> Note On Linux and Mac OS X hosts the number of host-only interfaces is
>   limited to 128. There is no such limit for Solaris and Windows hosts.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)).

Comment: From the markdown link: "Simple blockquotes - Add a `>` to the beginning of any line to create a blockquote.`

Comment: Thanks David, i never noticed that " button next to the link Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

well, i found the issue. In virtual box, if you clone a machine, sometimes they go about and keep the same physical address on the network. So i just removed the machine and reinstalled it. It acquired a new address and i could ping away after allowing TCMP rules in the firewall.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can just update the MAC (physical) address in the network menu with no effort.